# Getting empty fields when deserializing JSON to my classes containing dictionaries

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a problem writing the classes to deserialize a JSON file.

My classes look like this:

```
public class Button1
{
    public string Caption = "";
    public Dictionary<string, Button1> Buttons;
}

public class ButtonsMenu
{
    public Dictionary<string, Button1> Buttons;
}
```

and I am trying to deserialize this JSON:

```
{
  "Buttons": {
    "Activity": {
      "btn1": {
        "Caption": "Promeni sostojba"
      },
      "btn2": {
        "Caption": "Izvrsi nesto drugo"
      }
    },
    "Navigate": {
      "btnA": {
        "Caption": "Pojdi na druga forma"
      },
      "btnB": {
        "Caption": "Otvori nesto razlicno"
      }
    },
    "Print": {
      "btnX1": {
        "Caption": "Pecati nalog"
      },
      "btnX2": {
        "Caption": "Pecati report"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the use of Json.Net like this:

```
var buttonDef = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ESB.Shared.DTO.ButtonsMenu>(formDefJson);
```

My problem is when I try to deserialize my JSON, I have the three items `Activity`, `Navigate` and `Print` but the field `Captions` is empty everywhere.
Can you please tell me what I am missing in my classes?

Comment: why are you setting it as empty string by default ? `public string Caption = ""`

Comment: If it doesnt have value to be empty string and not null

Comment: You have two levels here, Activity is another dictionary, try making the Buttons in ButtonsMenu into this: `public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Button1>> Buttons;`.

Answer (score 0):

use classes

```
public class Btn1
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class Btn2
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public Btn1 btn1 { get; set; }
    public Btn2 btn2 { get; set; }
}

public class BtnA
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class BtnB
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class Navigate
{
    public BtnA btnA { get; set; }
    public BtnB btnB { get; set; }
}

public class BtnX1
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class BtnX2
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class Print
{
    public BtnX1 btnX1 { get; set; }
    public BtnX2 btnX2 { get; set; }
}

public class Buttons
{
    public Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public Navigate Navigate { get; set; }
    public Print Print { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Buttons Buttons { get; set; }
}
```

or use service to generate classes http://json2csharp.com/
hope i help you :)

**Update:** if you want use dictionary try this

```
public class Button1
{
    public string Caption;
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Button1>> Buttons;
}

public class ButtonsMenu
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Button1>> Buttons;
}
```

Comment: i am using dictionary and this is more complex classes , but thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because your JSON doesn't match your class structure exactly.  There are two ways to fix it-- either change your classes or change the JSON.

If you want the change the JSON to make it work with your existing classes, then you need an additional `Buttons` level surrounding the inner buttons objects like this:

```
{
  "Buttons": {
    "Activity": {
      "Buttons": {
        "btn1": {
          "Caption": "Promeni sostojba"
        },
        "btn2": {
          "Caption": "Izvrsi nesto drugo"
        }
      }
    },
    "Navigate": {
      "Buttons": {
        "btnA": {
          "Caption": "Pojdi na druga forma"
        },
        "btnB": {
          "Caption": "Otvori nesto razlicno"
        }
      }
    },
    "Print": {
      "Buttons": {
        "btnX1": {
          "Caption": "Pecati nalog"
        },
        "btnX2": {
          "Caption": "Pecati report"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vAWhUd

If you would rather change your classes to fit the JSON in your question, then you need to change the outer `Buttons` dictionary to be a nested dictionary:

```
public class ButtonsMenu
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Button1>> Buttons;
}

public class Button1
{
    public string Caption = "";
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1KbQoD